# Prove that $T_\Omega( f )$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a nonzero integrable function on $S^{n−1}$ with mean value zero. Let
$f \geq 0$ be nonzero and integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $T_\Omega( f )$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

The definition of $T_\Omega( f ) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0, N \to \infty}{}\int_{\epsilon \leq |y| \leq N} f(x-y) \frac{\Omega(y/|y|)}{|y|^ n} dy$.

I would like to know how to show this statement. First I wanted to show $\widehat{T_\Omega(f) } $ cannot be continuous at zero.But I don't know how to prove it.

Also I think that in this excersise we need the hypothesis that $\Omega \not = 0 \quad a.s$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If the Fourier transform $\hat{g}$ is not continuous at some point, then the function $g$ is not absolutely integrable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but How could I show that the fourier transformation of $T_\Omega$ cannot be continous at zero? @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: The Fourier transform of the expression under the limit  is equal the product of  $\hat{f},$ which is continuous and $\hat{f}(0)>0,$ and the Fourier transform of the function the indicator function of $\varepsilon <|x|<N$ times $\Omega(x/|x|)|x|^{-n}$. It should be possible to determine by applying the polar coordinates. The Fourier transform involves only the imaginary part due to the mean value equal zero. Then the limit when $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ and $N\to \infty $ should be calculated. I would start with $n=2$ and see what is going to occur.